# Tipagem DATETIME

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estou criando um banco de dados e nele tem um campo que recebe uma data, eu gostaria que aparecesse somente a data. Se uso o tipo `datetime` vem com a hora também. E no SQL Server tem a opção do tipo `date`, mas na hora de fazer no C# não tem esse tipo, só tem o `datetime`.

Como posso fazer para remover a hora no C#?

Ou tem como usar o tipo `datetime` e remover a hora no SQL Server?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você está usando algum framework ORM, tipo o entity?

Comment: Estou utilizando o entity framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você comentou que está utilizando o Entity Framework, você pode fazer uma das seguintes maneiras:

1 - Atribuindo o tipo na Model:

```
[Column(TypeName="Date")]
public DateTime Data { get; set; }
```

2 - Utilizando o Fluent API, adicionando o seguinte código no método `OnModelCreating`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Titulo>().Property(p => p.Data).HasColumnType("Date");
}
```

Lembrando que você precisa adicionar o import:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

Depois disso, recrie ou altere a sua tabela, caso esteja utilizando Migrations.

Answer (score 2):

Tem que utilizar a propriedade `Date`:

```
var dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
var date = dateAndTime.Date;
```

A variável `date` vai conter a data, a parte do tempo ficará com o valor `00:00:00`.

Mais informação sobre a propriedade `Date` [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_Date).

---

Depende também da forma como insere os registos na base de dados e como a coluna de data está configurada no SQL. O ideal será ser do tipo `Date`.